# Program with <error> as if it was a type when using import

Tags: eclipse, scala, class, import

I'm working with Eclipse and have two files (main/scala/global and test/scala/dataSourcer). On the first I have:

```
package main.scala.global
class Date(day : Int, month : Int, year : Int) {
  override def toString() : String = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
}
```

On the second I have a worksheet:

```
package test.scala.dataSourcer
import main.scala.global._

object classDate {
  val date01 = new Date(1,1,2015) //> date01  : <error> = 1/1/2015
}
```

Why does the type is not prompted in the worksheet?

The error changes if I define the class inside the worksheet as follows:

```
package test.scala.dataSourcer

object classDate {
  class Date(day : Int, month : Int, year : Int) {
    override def toString() : String = day + "/" + month + "/" + year
  }  
  val date01 = new Date(1,1,2015) //> date01  : test.scala.dataSourcer.classDate.Date = 1/1/2015
}
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by closing Eclipse and opening again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by closing Eclipse and opening it again.